# Extracting k from Yellow brick KElbowVisualizer

Tags: python, k-means, yellowbrick, yellow

I am trying to extract the value of k from Yellow brick KElbowVisualizer visualizer for further processing. I can see the k value on the visualization, but I cannot seem to extract it and put in a variable.

Comment: Hi, Can you share your code that you tried, and expected output?

Answer (score 3):

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer

# Generate synthetic dataset with 8 random clusters
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=12, centers=8, random_state=42)

# Instantiate the clustering model and visualizer
model = KMeans()
visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(model, k=(4,12))

visualizer.fit(X)        # Fit the data to the visualizer
visualizer.show()        # Finalize and render the figure
visualizer.elbow_value_ # Get elbow value
```